# forEach is not defined -- why?

Tags: javascript, foreach

In *Eloquent JavaScript*, 1st ed, page 77, it gives an example of building a mapping function from scratch:

```
function mapFunc(func, array) {
var result = []; // not touching the original!
console.log("array:", array)
forEach(array, function(element) {
    result.push(func(element));
    });
    return result;
}
```

Seems pretty straightforward but when it's run like this:

```
console.log(mapFunc(Math.round, [0.01, 2, 9.89, Math.PI]))
```

It throws an error:

```
ReferenceError: forEach is not defined
```

Even when I change things up to match the es6 syntax more, same issue:

```
array.forEach(function(element) {
    result.push(func(element))
    console.log(element)
})
```

I've been messing with it for a while and can't figure out what the problem might be or why `forEach` suddenly becomes undefined.  Thoughts?

Comment: should be this --> `console.log(mapFunc(Math.round, [0.01, 2, 9.89, Math.PI]))`

Comment: Did you remember to read all the text that came before it? On its own, tthis code won't run because it's not using standard JS syntax. However, given that this is code from a book, and that it teaches you to builds a function that _already exists in JS_ from scratch, I assume it also already showed you how to write your own `forEach` from scratch (why you'd do this is beyond me, but it seems reasonable to assume you simply forgot to do the previous exercises) and this code simply builds on that.

Comment: so did you make a forEach function?

Comment: Also, which edition are you using? The third edition, https://eloquentjavascript.net, does not teach you to do this. It knows full well that `map` and `forEach` are built in and teaches you to use those.

Comment: Transcription error.  And I did read the text before, but glossed over that creation of the forEach...dangit!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `array.forEach`, and you need to call `mapFunc()` correctly. You're passing the array as the second argument to `console.log()` rather than `mapFunc()`.

```js
function mapFunc(func, array) {
  var result = []; // not touching the original!
  console.log("array:", array)
  array.forEach(function(element) {
    result.push(func(element));
  });
  return result;
}

console.log(mapFunc(Math.round, [0.01, 2, 9.89, Math.PI]));
```

The book defines a `forEach()` function of its own earlier in the chapter.

```
function forEach(array, action) {
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
    action(array[i]);
}
```

If you add that function to your code, you should be able to use the `mapFunc()` function as you first wrote it. But you need to call `mapFunc()` correctly in either case.

Comment: Pretty sure they actually need to read the book, though. The example code implements mapping "from scratch", so it's a good bet the book already taught the reader how to implement a function called `forEach` prior, and this code simply refers back to that implementation.

Comment: I don't have a copy of the book, so I don't know how far they're going "from scratch". Are they buying a chicken from the grocery store, or do they have their own chicken ranch?

Comment: For some unfathomable reason, it appears they're starting at the lumberyard so they can build the ranch, first. (also, the book's free; https://eloquentjavascript.net, and at least the current version acknowledges that `.map` and `.forEach` are built in)

Comment: I don't consider it "unfathomable". Programmers should learn how things work, not just how to put together a Lego set.

Comment: Fair... JS has also changed face a lot over the last few years, so I suppose at the time of the first edition, iterating was something that jQuery gave you, rather than vanilly JS, so showing how to implement it yourself made sense.

Comment: Yeah, I wanted to edit my question to remind him to include the `forEach` definition from a previous page, but your link is to the edition that doesn't have it.

Comment: The author was smart enough to keep the 1st and 2nd edition online, but deemphasized. https://eloquentjavascript.net/1st_edition/chapter6.html

Comment: I did indeed read the book but was assuming that I could just use the existing forEach function. I've been a programmer for a while, was just perusing the book. And decided to check out this example.  Thanks @Barmar!  @Mike you made some interesting points, and considerable metaphors.